# Could I spell 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 as one billion billion?

Tags: numerals

I'm trying to understand numerals spelling. So, could I spell 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 as "one billion billion"?

Comment: In what context would you need such huge number?

Comment: Operations per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 
Although there is a "official" number for that ([Quintillion or Trillion, depending on the region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)) that you would use in scientific papers and official reports billion billion is somewhat more relatable.

As such has a place in unofficial writing and things intended for the kind of people who might not know what a quintillion is.

Answer (score 3):

Using "billion billion" is not incorrect, but this expressions may be difficult to grasp or understand quickly. It may be good for giving a general idea or for impressing people.

More descriptive terms/phrases you can consider are

- Ten to the 18th power
- One followed by 18 zeros
- ExaOPS (see [Exascale computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exascale_computing), [Exa- prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exa-))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although one *quintillion* is the correct wording. (A quintillion is 1 followed by 18 zeros.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be one billion billions. Not one billion billion.